# SharePoint server 2013,visual studio 2013,visual web part

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-2013

In SharePoint Server 2013 I have a 4 list

1. Common List
2. HR list
3. Finance list
4. IT List

How can I achieve this solution please Modify this code Empstrength textbox I type above 50 and I select a HR list the data will store in commonlist and HR list.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists["CommonList"];
                    SPListItem listItem = list.Items.Add();

                    listItem["Department"] = Department.Text;
                    listItem["EmpStrength"] = EmpStrength.Text;
                    listItem["Description"] = Description.Text;
                    listItem["DueDate"] = DueDate.Text;

                    //UniqueId = int.Parse(listItem["ConnectID"].ToString());
                    // listItem["ConnectID"] = UniqueId + 1;
                    listItem["Status"] = Status.Text;
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    listItem.Update();
                    //Guid id = listItem.UniqueId;
                }
            }

        if ( 50 <= int.Parse(EmpStrength.Text))
        {
            Department.SelectedItem.Text = "HRList";
            SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
            SPList lis = web.Lists["HRList"];

            SPListItem lisItem = lis.Items.Add();
            lisItem["EmpStrength"] = EmpStrength.Text;
            lisItem["Status"] = Status.Text;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            lisItem.Update();
        }
        else if (50 <= int.Parse(EmpStrength.Text))
        {
            Department.SelectedItem.Text = "ITList";
            SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
            SPList lis = web.Lists["ITList"];

            SPListItem liss = lis.Items.Add();
            liss["EmpStrength"] = EmpStrength.Text;
            liss["Status"] = Status.Text;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            liss.Update();
        }
        else
        {
            Department.SelectedItem.Text = "FinanceList";
            SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
            SPList lis = web.Lists["FinanceList"];

            SPListItem liss = lis.Items.Add();
            liss["EmpStrength"] = EmpStrength.Text;
            liss["Status"] = Status.Text;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            liss.Update();
        }
    }
}
}

Department.SelectedItem.Text = "ITList";
Department.SelectedItem.Text = "HRList";
Department.SelectedItem.Text = "FinanceList";
```

is it correct..?

Dropdown selection not working here I entered above 50 it will store in Common list and HRlist. 
In dropdown I selected ITList or Finance List it will stored in only HRList and Commonlist. Please anyone modify this code.

Comment: Anyone give me a sample code for this how to achieve this solution.

Comment: Seeing such webpart, I believe you missed something. You should really empower native features of SharePoint : content types, list schemas, etc... helped with 3rd party product (nintex form for example). It's hard to explain briefly, but I think you should really considering exploring in depth how SP works. Rebuilding the ui is often like opening the pandora's box.

Comment: Your dropdown value retrieval logic is wrong. Have a look at my answer how i get the selected value from the dropdown and also use that value in the if condition with an AND operator.

Comment: i should give like this but error came .if (int.Parse(EmpStrength.Text) >50 && Department.SelectedValue = "HRList"  )

Comment: use SelectedItem.Text or show me your dropdown markup

Comment: copy and pase my code to your onclick method

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you get started:

In the onclick method of you submit button use If Else conditions to check the form values such as :

```
   using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {


            SPList list = web.Lists["CommonList"];

            SPListItem listItem = list.Items.Add();

            listItem["Department"] = Department.Text;
            listItem["EmpStrength"] = EmpStrength.Text;
            listItem["Description"] = Description.Text;
            listItem["DueDate"] = DueDate.Text;

            //UniqueId = int.Parse(listItem["ConnectID"].ToString());
            // listItem["ConnectID"] = UniqueId + 1;
            listItem["Status"] = Status.Text;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            listItem.Update();
            //Guid id = listItem.UniqueId;

           if ( 50 <= int.Parse(EmpStrength.Text) && Department.SelectedItem.Text == "HRList")
{


   // SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
    //SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    SPList lis = web.Lists["HRList"];

    SPListItem lisItem = lis.Items.Add();
    lisItem["EmpStrength"] = EmpStrength.Text;
    lisItem["Status"] = Status.Text;
    //web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    lisItem.Update();
}
else if (50 <= int.Parse(EmpStrength.Text) &&Department.SelectedItem.Text =="ITList")
{

   // SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
   // SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
   SPList  lis = web.Lists["ITList"];

    SPListItem liss = lis.Items.Add();
    liss["EmpStrength"] = EmpStrength.Text;
    liss["Status"] = Status.Text;
    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    liss.Update();
}
else if(Department.SelectedItem.Text == "FinanceList")
{

   // SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url);
    //SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();
    SPList lis = web.Lists["FinanceList"];

    SPListItem liss = lis.Items.Add();
    liss["EmpStrength"] = EmpStrength.Text;
    liss["Status"] = Status.Text;
   // web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
    liss.Update();

}
 web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
    }
```

Below link shows code example for adding a new list item to a list

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ms470423.aspx

Comment: Actually i am new to this field i dont know how to store data in 4 list based on that dropdown list.

Comment: You can get the value of dropdown list either by using dropdownlist.SelectedValue or dropdownlist.SelectedItem or dropdownlist.SelectedIndex properties. I have updated my answer accordingly. Have a look here for more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Use a native list with your fields. Plug a small a simple workflow that route the item to either of the list, depending on the value. Do not solve this problem with webparts!

Comment: hi,Now i edited my code just see my code and give me a solution, Advance thanks.

Comment: cool. Dont forget to mark as answer :)

Comment: Great! Please mark as answer if this has helped you..